# Typeerror for sort

Tags: python

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-130-50c833fafd4b> in <module>
      1 import pandas as pd
----> 2 df_college.groupby('Name')['PercUG'].unique().sort_values(by='PercUG',ascending=False)

TypeError: sort_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'by'
```

Which are the 5 colleges with highest percentage of undergraduates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the corrected code to get the top 5 colleges with the highest percentage of undergraduates:

```py
top_5_colleges_p = df_college.groupby('Name')['PercUG'].unique().sort_values(ascending=False).head(5)
print(top_5_colleges_p)
```